# Hide wordpress menu items based on civicrm contact fields?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, menu

Is there a way to hide a wordpress menu item based on custom fields in the civicrm contact record?

Comment: Wanna expand your question a little? A wordpress menu item would not normally be associated with a specific contact record. If you're auto-generating menu items from contact records, then that code might be able to include a class based on the value of a custom field, and then you could use some css or javascript.

Comment: Or are you hiding the menu item based on the custom field value of the logged in contact? A use-case description would help.

Comment: Of course. My idea was, based on the custom field value of a logged in contact to show or hide a menu item. 
The reason behind this was wanting to provide menu items with links to surveys, that will disappear once completed. 

I have decided to send contacts links to these instead, using the information here:
https://aghstrategies.com/content/how-create-one-click-personalized-links-civicrm-emails